# Decrease font for sub menus [wordpress]

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, hover

I have a website at: http://chemipharmaceutical.com/wp/

When you hover over "Our Services' a popout sub menu appears. I am having trouble changing the font size to make it smaller. I am sure I am not targeting the right class, I have tried almost every possible combination.

Currently, I set all the font to a larger size by using:

```
.widget li {
    font-size:1.6rem;
}
```

This affects all menus, including sub menus as you can see. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try targeting the submenu directly with:

```
.widget .sub-menu a {
   font-size:9px;
}
```